# Why did TF2 suddenly spike in file size?

Tags: team-fortress-2

I've been cutting down on disk usage recently, and I recall TF2's file size to be about 9 GB (`C:\\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Team Fortress 2`)  My total free disk space was about 11 GB.

Now, I only have 7 GB on my hard drive, a substantial decrease.  I checked the size of the programs I recently installed, but they only added up to ~1.5 GB.  I suspected TF2, and I was correct: Its file size was 16 GB!

Is there any explanation for this sudden increase is file size? What can I do to reduce it?

Comment: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/21452/why-is-the-team-fortress-2-install-so-huge

Comment: @TreeHouseFalcon That question is about why TF2 uses so much space after a fresh download.  I am asking why I am experiencing a spike in disk space usage.

Comment: Have you been connecting to servers that use custom maps?

Comment: @Powerlord Yes, but I have recently cleared all of my custom content (except mods).  I have only played on 2 Skial servers using vanilla maps after the wipe.

Comment: I'd still check the download and downloads directory to see how large they are.

Comment: My `download` folder currently takes 41 MB.   My mods add up to 70 MB.  All of the vanilla maps that come installed add up to about 2 GB, but that should only change on major updates.

Comment: It sounds like it is time for a new hard drive.  Maybe move some files to a USB stick?

Comment: @chicks Thanks for the suggestion, but most of my documents are already on Google Drive.  Most of my space seems be used by `C:\\Users\%USER%\AppData` though, maybe that's a sign of something?

Comment: Have you tried using software like [WinDirStat](https://windirstat.info/)?

Comment: More importantly: you've only got 11GB left? Might be time to consider getting another HDD if you can...

Answer (score 3):

First of all scriptHero the game itself is very large, especially since they update it frequently. Also, like @Powerlord said, going to any server with custom maps, sounds, or models will download more things to your TF2 directory. The sudden spike of file size is most likely the updates, since they are pretty big. (The most recent one was almost 200 mb!)

[Why is the Team Fortress 2 install so huge?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/21452/why-is-the-team-fortress-2-install-so-huge?lq=1)
This is somebody's question about why the file size is so large, so that may help too.